# Trouble with functions and defining variables in them

Tags: python, function

So I can't really figure out why the variables "first" and "second" aren't defined even when returning them it doesn't work maybe I'm doing it wrong I honestly have no clue.

The assignment is to make a times table tester using only functions to give us an understanding of functions.
My teacher gave us what the functions are supposed to do so I will put these below.

```py
def results_summary(right, answered):
    """ right is int for number of correct questions
    answered is int rep. total number of questions
    display results of practice with ratio
    and percentage correct """
```

```py
def generate_question():
    """ generate and display a random multiplication
    questions with factors from 1 to 12
    return the answer as an integer value """
```

```py
def get_answer():
    """ display = to prompt user to enter answer
    returns input if valid integer entry is made
    displays message and new prompt for invalid entry """
```

```py
def goAgain():
    """ Asks the user y/n if they want another question
    returns True for 'y' and False for 'n'
    displays message and new prompt for invalid entry """
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```py
import random
#defines important functions
def results_summary(num_correct, num_question):
    percentage = num_correct / num_question * 100
    correctCount = str(num_correct)
    questionCount = str(num_question)
    percentage = str(round(percentage))
    print('You got ' + correctCount + '/' + questionCount + ' (' + percentage + '%).')
def generate_question():
    first = random.randint(1,12)
    second = random.randint(1,12)
    correct_answer = second * first
    return correct_answer
def get_answer():
    try:
        user_answer = input('What is ' + first + ' x ' + second + '?')
    except ValueError:
        print('Please Enter Integers Only.')
def goAgain():
    input('Do you want another question? (y / n)')
    try:
        'y' == True
        'n' == False
    except ValueError:
        print('Please Enter a valid response. (y / n)')
        
#MAIN  PROGRAM
num_correct = 0
num_question = 0
#creates while loop to continuously ask questions
while True:
    correct_answer = generate_question()
    user_answer = get_answer()
    #prints if the user answers correctly
    if user_answer == correct_answer:
        print('Correct')
        num_question += 1
        num_correct += 1
        
    again = goAgain()

    if goAgain == False:
        break

results_summary(num_correct, num_question)
```

Comment: You don't return *variables*, you return the *values* of the variables.  (You return the value of `corerct_answer` anyway). `goAgain` has several problems: you are ignoring the return value of `input`, and you are making two pointless comparisons of strings to boolean values that will never raise `ValueError`s.

Comment: `return x` does not mean "make the variable `x` visible to the caller".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry budd :(

I got no time to explain ... **[I'm in a hurry]** but I don't want you to get disrespect from your teacher !, I been there :/

So here is the **modified working code** , **hope it helps :)**

```
import random
#defines important functions

def results_summary(num_correct, num_question):
    percentage = (num_correct / num_question) * 100
    print(f"You got {round(percentage)} %")
def generate_question():
    global first 
    global second
    first = random.randint(1,12)
    second = random.randint(1,12)
    correct_answer = second * first
    return correct_answer

def get_answer():
    try:
        user_answer = int(input('What is ' + str(first) + ' x ' + str(second) + '?'))
        return user_answer
    except ValueError:
        print('Please Enter Integers Only.')

def goAgain():
    confo = input('Do you want another question? (y / n)')
    if confo.lower() == 'y':
        return True
    elif confo.lower() == "n":
        return False
    else:
        return        

#MAIN  PROGRAM
num_correct = 0
num_question = 0

#creates while loop to continuously ask questions
while True:
    correct_answer = generate_question()
    user_answer = get_answer()
    #prints if the user answers correctly
    if user_answer == correct_answer:
        print('Correct')
        num_question += 1
        num_correct += 1
    else:
        num_question += 1
        print("Wrong answer")
        
    again = goAgain()
    if again:
        pass
    else:
        print("Have a great day!, bye")
        break

    if goAgain == False:
        break

results_summary(num_correct, num_question)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows variables `first` and `second` to be undefined because the variables you are using in:

```
user_answer = input('What is ' + first + ' x ' + second + '?')
```

command inside the `get_answer()` function, are undefined.

In order to use these variables, just change the function `generate_question()` to:

```
def generate_question():
    global first, second
    first = random.randint(1,12)
    second = random.randint(1,12)
    correct_answer = second * first
    return correct_answer
```

and change the input command inside `get_answer()` function to:

```
user_answer = input('What is ' + str(first) + ' x ' + str(second) + '?')
```

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: @Phoness happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.